# Consistent handling of DateTimes in different RDBMSs

Tags: datetime, timezone, rdbms

I'm planning a distributed system of applications that will communicate with different types of RDBMS. One of the requirements is consistent handling of DateTimes across all RDBMS types. All DateTime values must be at millisecond precision, include the TimeZone info and be stored in a single column.

Since different RDBMS's handle dates and times differently, I'm worried I can't rely on their native column types in this case and so I'll have to come up with a different solution. (If I'm wrong here, you're welcome to show me the way.)

The solution, whatever it may be, should ideally allow for easy sorting and comparisons on the SQL level. Other aspects, such as readability and ability to use SQL datetime functions, are not important, since this will all be handled by a gateway service.

I'm toying with an idea of storing my DateTime values in an unsigned largeint column type (8 bytes). I haven't made sure if all RDBMS's in question (MSSQL, Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, MySQL, maybe a few others) actually /have/ such a type, but at this point I just assume they do.

As for the storage format... For example, 2009-01-01T12:00:00.999+01:00 could be stored similar to ?20090101120000999??, which falls in under 8 bytes.

The minimum DateTime I'd be able to store this way would be 0001-01-01T00:00:00.000+xx:xx, and the maximum would be 8000-12-31T23:59:59.999+xx:xx, which gives me more than enough of a span.

Since maximum unsigned largeint value is 18446744073709551615, this leaves me with the following 3 digits (marked by A and BB) to store the TimeZone info: AxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxBB.

Taking into account the maximum year span of 0001..8000, A can be either 0 or 1, and BB can be anywhere from 00 to 99.

And now the questions:

- What do you think about my proposed solution? Does it have merit or is it just plain stupid?
- If no better way exists, how do you propose the three remaining digits be used for TimeZone info best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One of the requirements is consistent handling of DateTimes across all RDBMS types.

Be aware that date-time handling capabilities vary *radically* across various database systems. This ranges from virtually no support (SQLite) to excellent (Postgres). Some such as Oracle have legacy data-types that may confuse the situation, so study carefully without making assumptions.

Rather than establish a requirement that broadly says we must support "any or all database", you should get more specific. Research exactly what databases might realistically be candidates for deployment in the real-world. A requirement of "any or all databases" is naïve and unrealistic because databases vary in many capabilities — date-time handling is just the beginning of your multi-database support concerns.

The SQL standard barely touches on the subject of date-time, broadly defining a few types with little discussion of the nuances and complexities of date-time work.

Also be aware that most programming platforms provide atrociously poor support for date-time handling. Note that Java leads the industry in this field, with its brilliantly designed *java.time* classes. That framework evolved from the [*Joda-Time*](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project for Java which was ported to .Net platform as [*NodaTime*](https://nodatime.org/).

> All DateTime values must be at millisecond precision,

Good that you have specified that important detail. Understand that various systems resolve date-time values to whole seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds, or something else.

> include the TimeZone info and be stored in a single column.

Define time zone precisely.

Understand the difference between an offset-from-UTC and a time zone: The first is a number of hours-minutes-seconds plus-or-minus, the second [has a name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in format `Continent/Region` and is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.

The 2-4 letter abbreviations such as CST, PST, IST, and so on are *not* formal time zone names, are not standardized, and are not even unique (avoid them).

> Since different RDBMS's handle dates and times differently, I'm worried I can't rely on their native column types in this case and so I'll have to come up with a different solution.

The SQL standard does define a few types that are supported by some major databases.

- `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline. I vaguely recall hearing of a database that actually stored the incoming time zone. But most, such as Postgres, use the time zone indicated on the incoming value to adjust into UTC, then store that UTC value, and lastly, discard the zone info. When retrieved, you get back a UTC value. Beware of tools and middleware with the confusing anti-feature of applying a default time zone after retrieval and before display to the user.
- `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` represents a date with time-of-day, but purposely lacking the context of a time zone or offset. Without a zone/offset, such a value does *not* represent a moment. You could apply a time zone to determine a moment in a range of about 26-27 hours, the range of time zones around the globe.

There are other types in the standard as well such as date-only (`DATE`) and time-only (`TIME`).

See this table I made for Java, but in this context the column of SQL standard types in relevant. Be aware that `TIME WITH TIME ZONE` makes no sense logically, and should not be used.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

If you have narrowed down your list of candidate databases, study their documentation to learn if they have a type akin to the standard types in which you are interested, and what the name of that type is (not always the standard name).

> I'm toying with an idea of storing my DateTime values in an unsigned largeint column type (8 bytes).

A 64-bit value is not likely appropriate. For example, the *java.time* classes use a pair of numbers, a number of whole seconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, plus another number for the count of nanoseconds in the fractional second.

It is really best to use the database's data-time data types if they are similar across your list of candidate databases. Using a count-from-epoch is inherently ambiguous, which makes identifying erroneous data difficult.

Storing your own count-from-epoch number is possible. If you must go that way, be sure the entire team understands what epoch reference was chosen. At least a [couple dozen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) have been in use in various computing systems. Beware of staff persons *assuming* a particular epoch reference is in use.

Another way to define your own date-time tracking is to use text in the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. Such strings will alphabetically sort as chronological. One exception to that sorting is the optional but commonly used `Z` at the end to indicate an offset-from-UTC of zero (pronounced “Zulu”).

> The minimum DateTime I'd be able to store this way would be 0001-01-01T00:00:00.000+xx:xx,
>
> Taking into account the maximum year span of 0001..8000

Are you really storing values from the time of Christ? Is this software really going to be around executing transactions for the year 8000?

This is an area where the responsible stakeholders should define their real needs. For example, for many business systems you may need only data from the year of the product's launch and run out only a century or two into the future.

The minimum/maximum value range varies *widely* between different databases. If you choose to use a built-in data type in each database system, investigate its limits. Some, for example, may go only to the year 2038, the common [Y2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

To sum up my recommendation:

- Get real about your date-time needs: min/max range, resolution, and various types (**moment versus not a moment**, date-only, etc.).
- Get real about your [possible databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_relational_database_management_systems) for deployment.

  - If you need enterprise-quality reliability in a classic [RDMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database), your candidate list is likely only a few: [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), [Microsoft SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server), [Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database), and maybe [IBM Db2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Db2_Family).
  - Keep this list of supported databases as short as possible. Each database you agree to support is a *huge* commitment, now and in the future.
  - Be sure your chosen database(s) have a database driver available for your chosen programming language(s). For example [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) for [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform)).
- If at all possible, use the built-in data types offered by the database.
- Be sure you and your team understand date-time handling. Many do not, in my experience, as (a) the subject is rarely taught, and (b) many programmers & admins mistakenly believe their quotidian intuitive understanding of date-time is sufficient for programming work. (Ignorance is bliss, as they say.)
- Identify other areas of functionality beyond date-time handling, and compare which databases support those areas.

Comment: Wow, this was a blast from the past. 11 years since I asked! :) I'm accepting it for thoroughness alone! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to store the datetime information in milliseconds since 1970 (Java style) .
It's a standard way for storing datetime information, in addition it's more efficient in terms of space than your suggestion. Because in your suggestion some digits are "wasted" i.e. the month digits can store only 00-12 (instead of 00-99) and so on.
You didn't specify what is your development language but I am sure you can find many code snippets that transform date to milliseconds.
If you are developing in .NET they have a similar concept of ticks. (you can use this information as well)

Regarding the time zone,I would have add another column to store only the TimeZone indication.

Remember that any format you choose should maintain consistency between two dates, i.e. if D1 > D2 then format(D1)>format(D2) , this way you can query the DB for changes since some date, or query for changes between two dates

Comment: Num. of milliseconds since 1970 translates to using 6 bytes for current DateTime values, which is exactly the same in efficiency as my proposed 8 bytes, regardless of wasted digits.

About your last paragraph on consistency and querying... Do you believe my proposed solution doesn't cover those? Thx

Comment: How do 6 bytes the same as 8 bytes. Regarding the your question I didn't fully understand what does the first digit used for? Because it will determine the comparison result between 2 dates.

Comment: Well, I know of no numeric column type that would take 6 bytes. It's either 4 (int) or 8 (largeint), nothing in between. So if something takes 5 or 6 bytes, you need to go with largeint anyway.

As for the leading digit: you make a good point. I guess this rules it out automatically.